# I had an issue with functionality of contains only in karate?

Tags: karate

While working with assertion in karate I had two big arrays around 5000 lines each and while using contains only it behaves differently like

```
 * match array1 contains only aaray2
```

It gives assertion failure while on other hand

```
 * match array2 contains only array1
```

It works fine and does not through any error ?

Comment: maybe it is a bug so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: @PeterThomas yeah sure if I will be able to produce the same using some open source  I will follow back to you

Comment: I hope you noticed that you have a typo `aaray2`

Comment: @PeterThomas yeah sorry for that actually I am using this names just for illustration